# The data protection operation was unsuccessful

Tags: okta, kentor-authservices

I'm trying to get the sample MVC application from Kentor AuthServices deployed to Azure and using Okta as the IDP. I've jumped a few hurdles but have stumbled on the CryptographicException "The data protection operation was unsuccessful". I'm unsure how to resolve it.

When this occurs the URL in the browser is https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/AuthServices/Acs

Any assistance is appreciated, thanks.

Below is the kentor section of my web.config. I don't have an identity server so removed all the federation config..

```
<kentor.authServices entityId="https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/AuthServices"
               returnUrl="https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/"
               authenticateRequestSigningBehavior="Never">
<identityProviders>
  <add entityId="http://www.okta.com/1111111"
       allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect" 
       metadataLocation="https://dev-11111.oktapreview.com/app/1111111/sso/saml/metadata"
       loadMetadata="true">
    <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/okta.cert" />
  </add>
</identityProviders>
```

Let me know if I can provide any further info to assist you in assisting me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually an Azure issue [as Anders points out](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/427). The fix was to add the following to web.config:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in Kentor.AuthServices. I've recently done some rewriting which makes use of data protection API so something might be wrong there. Please file an issue at the [github site](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) and include the stack trace of the exception as well as information on what API module you are using (MVC, HttpModule or OWIN).

Comment: Ok thanks Anders. I've raised an issue (https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/427). I'll remove this post later if it is a bug.

Comment: @steve Better to leave this here for others to find if they run into the same problem.